# Internal Kinds Returned When Retrieving All Entities Belonging to a Particular Namespace

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, gcloud-python, google-cloud-python

I am trying to retrieve all entities belonging to a particular namespace. The query is quite simple

```
query = datastore.Query(namespace=<namespace>)
```

Running this however returns keys belonging to internal kinds which aren’t part of the data I am storing, for example I get entities belonging to this kind:

```
__Stat_Ns_Kind_IsRootEntity__
```

Do you know how I can prevent this? Can I refine my query to exclude these?

Comment: Is this using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gcloud? What version? Those looks like stats entities (which are useful for getting application stats). What namespace did you use for that?

Comment: gcloud v0.5, and I was using a non-default namespace I've created.

Comment: 1) Can you upgrade to the latest? 2) I'm not sure how those entities have ended up there, but would be happy to discuss more in an issue: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python/issues/new

Comment: I am having the same problem (But using go to wipe a namespace). That link you provide doesn't appear to link to an issue, but a request to create a new issue, which I probably don't want to do since I assume an issue was already raised? @bossylobster

Comment: That link was a suggestion that someone file an issue